# Why is p4 plugin in Jenkins failing?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am trying to set up a job in Jenkins using this [p4 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin).  I successfully installed the plugin and set up the p4 configuration to point to my company's p4 executable.

Now the actual failure happens when I build the project.  I am seeing the following:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on scspr0011492003.gdl.englab.netapp.com (scspr0011492003) in workspace /tmp/workspace/TestP4
Using remote perforce client: test--2000486220
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 workspace -o test--2000486220
Last build changeset: 2464123
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //test--2000486220/...
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -s changes -s submitted //test--2000486220/...@2464124,@2515192
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 describe -s 2515192
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -G where //...
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -s users alirezam
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 user -o alirezam
Sync'ing workspace to changelist 2515192.
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -s sync //test--2000486220/...@2515192
Sync complete, took 1755 ms
[TestP4] $ /usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -xe /tmp/hudson6814857322401659205.sh
(b4p4: for help on the 'b4p4' wrapper, use 'p4 b4p4help'; p4 -V for version)
Perforce client error:
open for read: e: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure what -xe is in p4 and not sure why it's failing.  Can someone help?  Thank you.

Comment: `-x filename` : Read arguments, one per line, from the specified file. To read arguments from standard input, specify "-x -". For ex., p4 -x myargs.txt

Comment: What did you put in the "Execute shell" build step? Maybe something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here appears to be a combination of things. Wrong p4 command syntax and a possible non-valid file name.

The ‘-x’ global option in Perforce is for feeding a list of files as arguments to a command. For example, see the reference here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/global.options.html

I see a couple of things wrong with this command:

```
/usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -xe /tmp/hudson6814857322401659205.sh
```

1] Unless the ‘e’ is a file or file list it is not passing anything in

2] On that line, there is no Perforce command used with the global option -x. For example, a command such as ‘edit’ or ‘add’.

Should this line instead be perhaps like this?:

/usr/software/rats/bin/p4 -x /tmp/hudson6814857322401659205.sh edit

You could also try something like this here:

```
echo /tmp/hudson6814857322401659205.sh|p4 -x - edit
```

to see if you get the same error of “Perforce client error:
open for read: e: No such file or directory”? That error indicates that it might be returning something that is not a valid filename.